# Any statistics on how much time developers spend on fixing unit tests/integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, statistics

Can anyone provide a link to a respectfull webpage which shows statistics of how much time development teams spent on fixing unit tests that fails (unit test regression) ?

Regards

Comment: If using TDD, that would be (almost) 100%.

Comment: the answer really depends on the project details and the skill level of the developer.

Comment: it would also be quite meaningless unless you have a way to compare it to how much time you've saved by not debugging problems in the application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the case. I don't think there is a standard measurement of this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested to see statistics. In my experience maintaining unit tests take as much time as maintaining real code. A lot of times you don't have time to fix unit tests so they are obsolete and are useless. Unit tests are not worth the time in my opinion because code quality is not better with unit tests because they only detect simple bugs. Also TDD is making poorly designed applications or making more time spent on refactoring code to end up with as good a design as using UML.